# Django-nose strange output

Tags: python, django, nose

I am trying different testing tools for my django project. I am also new into django and python. 
I have installed django and django-nose on my virtualenv. I edited settings.py file as requested in django-nose documentation. When I run my tests with command python manage.py test app I get following output :

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

....

DEBUG 2012-12-17 01:04:20,647 generic (10716) generic.py:261 execute "SET FOREIG
N_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"
DEBUG 2012-12-17 01:04:20,661 generic (10716) generic.py:261 execute "SET FOREIG
N_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"

....

............F.F.............EEEEEE.EEEEEEE
```

There is lot of similiar lines with DEBUG at start, I represent them with those 4 dots. After all those lines follows test report which looks normal.

So question is, is there specific problem with my settings? Or is it normal nose output?

```
app/
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_one.py
        test_two.py
```

Place where are my tests stored. **init** contains test suite.

Py.test run my tests without any problems.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this comes from running [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) and [nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) at the same time.

You can comment out `south` if that's an option. If this doesn't work check out this neat solution:

http://pypede.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/disable-south-debug-logging-when-testing-apps-with-nose-in-django/

My output was similar, but slightly different:

```
execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"
execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"
...
execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"
execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" with params "[]"
```